# Store related keys as OID or strings in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb setup stores my data mostly de-normalized, I store just enough user data that I would like display with a post. But I still always store the _id of the related user or related post for say a vote. Some of the ids come from ajax calls(end up stored as strings) and others come directly from mongodb server side(get stored in the data type they come from OID), thus right now when I save these I have a mix of related ids as strings or OIDs. My questions is wether I should be converting them all to strings or all to OIDs?

Comment: When your _id comes from ajax call, where are they originated? If they are not in correct format they might not be able to convert to OID.

Answer (score 3):

ObjectIds. They're more space efficient and ObjectIds compares are faster than string compares. You should always convert the incoming string back to an ObjectId (e.g. oid = new ObjectId(string)). I can't really think of an exception where you'd want strings.

Comment: Key names, for instance? They can be only strings.

Comment: Hm, well wanting a scenario where you have ObjectIds and want to intentionally convert them to strings so you can use them as field values sounds like a bit of a schema issue. But you are right that that could be a reason. It's pretty out there though ;)