# MongoDB, Using Mongodb ObjectID between collections

Tags: php, mongodb

Using PHP and MongoDB, i have a collection called users and another one called forms in the same DB.

I am using the Mongodb ObjectID as user identifier for the documents in the forms collection, saving the users ObjectId as uid on each forms document.

I am going to create an index of the uid field in the forms collection, but my question is how i should save the users Objectid?

As of now I am saving it as a normal string like (simplified)

```
$collection->insert( array('formName'=>'The name','uid'=>'CURRENT_USERS_ObjectId_AS_string') );
```

Does this seem logic or is best practice in this case to create a Mongodb ObjectID for uid like

```
$collection->insert( array('formName'=>'The name','uid'=> new MongoId('CURRENT_USERS_ObjectId_AS_string')) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I am not familiar with PHP but the schema design that you have suggested is good.I am using a similar structure for my c# implementation.Just to be clear here is a sample of my schema design

```
Account Class

public  ObjectId Id{get;set;}
public   string  Email {get;set}
public   string  Password{get;set;}

User Class

 public ObjectId Id{get;set;} 
 public string  AccountId {get;set}//refers to the ID in the account.
```

Now if I want to query an account for any user I can simply query it using the accountId in the user class.

MongoDb calls this referencing technique as manual referencing and this is also the one that it recommends here is the link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I was looking for information from MongoDB like the one in the posted answer above, but did not find it. I am going for alternative one with an normal index as that is what both you and the vendor are suggesting in the article.

Answer (score 6):

The use of [manual references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#manual-references) is perfectly fine - recommended even. Only use [DbRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#dbref) if they offer specific benefits - such as permitting automatic de-referencing (a mongo script or php code can automatically know that foo points at collection x, with id y [in database z]).

### Different types is a bad design

However avoid type juggling.

Having what is effectively a foreign key in one collection, and it being a different type from that of the collection it's pointing at is a **bad** design. Type juggling is something to eliminate from development in general, not introduce.

### Think about the database

Code like this ran on the db should work:

```
form = db.forms.findOne();
user = db.users.findOne({_id: form.user_id});
```

And it shouldn't matter what type the users collection _id field is. With the schema in the question this code becomes:

```
form = db.forms.findOne();
user = db.users.findOne({_id: new MongoId(form.user_id)});
```

In and of itself, that's not a huge difference, but it means you have to think/remember to convert these references and it becomes problematic if/when a collection is created which uses a different type - it introduces inconsistencies.

Consider the following:

```
> school = db.schools.insert({_id: 123, name: "my school"});
> userId = new ObjectId();
> db.users.insert({_id: userId, name: "Me"});
> db.forms.insert({user_id: userId, school_id: 123});
```

Let's say that the school id is a unique code. if there's no possibility it could change - it's appropriate and a good idea to use as the _id field. Now, the school id and the user id are different types:

```
> db.forms.findOne();
{
"_id" : ObjectId("508940370392baf87e68e31d"),
"user_id" : ObjectId("5089401c0392baf87e68e31b"),
"school_id" : 123
}
```

If they are stored as-is, it's still possible to be completely ignorant of these different types in queries:

```
form = db.forms.findOne();
school = db.schools.findOne({_id: form.school_id});
user = db.users.findOne({_id: form.user_id});
```

If *different* types are used that means that it becomes necessary to think "with this collection I need to convert the string to an ObjectId, but with this one I **must** not".

That's a problem that could have been avoided, but instead - it was introduced.

Comment: A very good point, in a very good answer! In this case I will stick with storing the key as a string rather than en ObjectId as I am unsure if indexing the uid field in the forms collection will be as good if the field are of type ObjectId. Any thoughts on that? Consequences for indexing I mean.

Comment: There's an [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946267/store-related-keys-as-oid-or-strings-in-mongodb) which covers that. Object ids are smaller, and therefore faster to compare

Comment: Yeah good point about type juggling.Let me see if I can clean up my schema design.Thanks :)

Comment: @AD7six Sry for the follow-up. Just to make sure. Based on the examples in my question, you would go for alternative 2, using new Mongoid() when storing the uid, and not as string? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, store `forms.uid` exactly the same as `users._id`